# Calculating number of employees by month given begins date and end date in R

Tags: r

Here is a list of begin and end dates for employees. How can we calculate monthly number of Employees efficiently, given that there might be tens of thousands employees.

```
begin <- as.Date(c("2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-27","2015-07-06","2015-06-29",
               "2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-13","2015-06-29",
               "2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-13","2015-07-01","2015-07-06",
               "2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-09","2015-07-13"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")

end <- as.Date(c("2018-08-03","2016-01-11","2999-12-31","2017-03-13","2999-12-31",
             "2015-10-20","2999-12-31","2018-09-24","2999-12-31","2015-09-25",
             "2019-11-01","2999-12-31","2018-03-26","2018-08-08","2015-10-13",
             "2999-12-31","2999-12-31","2021-02-11","2999-12-31"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")

smallEmp <- data.frame(begin,end)


method_currentsolution = function() {
date_df = tibble(Date = seq(from=as.Date('2015-01-01'), to=Sys.Date(), by =   "month"))
queue_history = merge(smallEmp, date_df, all=TRUE) %>% 
filter(Date >= begin, Date <= end) %>%
group_by(Date) %>% 
summarise(cnt = n())
}

result <- method_currentsolution()
```

`smallEmp` is the dataset that holds the `Begin` and `End` dates.
This solution works, but it is slow for very large dataset since it repeats all employees for each month of interest. Any suggestion that would speed this up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R solution is

```r
date_df <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(from=as.Date('2015-01-01'), to=Sys.Date(), by = "month"))
date_df$count <- sapply(date_df$Date, function(x) sum(x >= begin & x <= end))
date_df <- subset(date_df, count > 0)
head(date_df, 10)
#R>          Date count
#R> 7  2015-07-01     3
#R> 8  2015-08-01    19
#R> 9  2015-09-01    19
#R> 10 2015-10-01    18
#R> 11 2015-11-01    16
#R> 12 2015-12-01    16
#R> 13 2016-01-01    16
#R> 14 2016-02-01    15
#R> 15 2016-03-01    15
#R> 16 2016-04-01    15
```

This is perhaps faster but it uses more peak memory

```r
date_df_2 <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(from=as.Date('2015-01-01'), to=Sys.Date(), by = "month"))
date_df_2$count <- 
  rowSums(outer(date_df_2$Date, begin, `>=`) & outer(date_df_2$Date, end, `<=`))
date_df_2 <- subset(date_df_2, count > 0)

# we got the same
all.equal(date_df_2, date_df)
#R> [1] TRUE
```

The two solutions can be written a bit more nicely in R 4.1.0 or later as follows

```r
date_df_3 <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), Sys.Date(), by = "month")) |>
  transform(count = sapply(Date, \(x) sum(x >= begin & x <= end))) |>
  subset(count > 0)

date_df_4 <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), Sys.Date(), by = "month")) |>
  transform(
    count = rowSums(outer(Date, begin, `>=`) & outer(Date, end, `<=`))) |>
  subset(count > 0)

# we got the same
all.equal(date_df_3, date_df)
#R> [1] TRUE
all.equal(date_df_4, date_df)
#R> [1] TRUE
```

You may want to change one of the `>=` and `<=` to a `>` or `<`.

---

Here is a simple benchmark which is created by repeating the data provided by the OP

```r
# repeat the data a number of times to create a larger data set
begin <- rep(begin, 1000)
end <- rep(end, 1000)
smallEmp <- data.frame(begin,end)
small_emp <- data.table(begin = begin, end = end)

# perform the benchmark
bench::mark(
  OP = method_currentsolution(),
  sapply = data.frame(
    Date = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), Sys.Date(), by = "month")) |>
    transform(count = sapply(Date, \(x) sum(x >= begin & x <= end))) |>
    subset(count > 0),
  rowSums = data.frame(
    Date = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), Sys.Date(), by = "month")) |>
    transform(
      count = rowSums(outer(Date, begin, `>=`) & outer(Date, end, `<=`))) |>
    subset(count > 0),
  data.table = {
    all_dates <- data.table(
      date = seq(from = as.Date('2015-01-01'), to = Sys.Date(), by = "month"))
    all_dates[small_emp, .N, on = .(date >= begin, date <= end), keyby = .(date)]
  },
  `data.table (by)` = {
    all_dates <- data.table(
      date = seq(from = as.Date('2015-01-01'), to = Sys.Date(), by = "month"))
    all_dates[small_emp, .N, on = .(date >= begin, date <= end), by = .(date)]
  },
  fuzzy_inner_join = method_fuzzy(smallEmp), check = FALSE, memory = FALSE)
#R> # A tibble: 6 x 13
#R>   expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time            gc               
#R>   <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <list>          <list>           
#R> 1 OP                  2.87s    2.87s    0.349         NA     1.74     1     5      2.87s <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [1]>  <tibble [1 × 3]> 
#R> 2 sapply             8.91ms   9.42ms   55.9           NA     7.71    29     4   518.53ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [29]> <tibble [29 × 3]>
#R> 3 rowSums           28.26ms  56.98ms   15.9           NA    24.7      9    14   566.25ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [9]>  <tibble [9 × 3]> 
#R> 4 data.table        23.34ms  23.89ms   25.8           NA     7.95    13     4   503.36ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [13]> <tibble [13 × 3]>
#R> 5 data.table (by)   23.22ms   28.4ms   33.9           NA     3.99    17     2   500.82ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [17]> <tibble [17 × 3]>
#R> 6 fuzzy_inner_join   16.09s   16.09s    0.0622        NA     8.21     1   132     16.09s <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [1]>  <tibble [1 × 3]>
```

The `sapply` solution is the fastest. It is about >2 times faster then the seconds fastest which is the `data.table` version. Thing may look different for other sized data (say millions of data points instead of 19000).

Comment: Nice! Impressive to see base R not only matching but _beating_ `data.table`. I'd give an extra +1 (if I could) for showing off the new pipe operator and lambda syntax. I'd also be curious how this scales up to the OP's data (50k records in `small_emp`).

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is the `keyby` with `data.table`. If the sorting was needed at some point prior, then the cost of sorting the data could be amortized. It cannot in this example.

Comment: Seems likely. Do you mind adding a version to your benchmark with just `by` instead of `keyby`? I only used `keyby` for parity with the Tidyverse version, it's probably not needed here.

Comment: I have added a solution where I replace `keyby` with `by`.

Comment: Negligible difference, I see. Thanks again.

Comment: I think a lot of solutions will perform waaaaaay faster if the year 2999 in the sample data is reduced to (let's say) 2030.

Comment: @Wimpel I have tried to change 2999 to 2023. `sapply` ran in 10.45ms, `data.table` ran in 27.05ms, `OP` ran in 3.91s, and `fuzzy_inner_join` ran in 17.11s (my system was not completely idle this time). So basically no change.

Comment: These are all great solutions. Some where more than 100 times faster than the original. In the original solution I was able to use grouping, so I could add Department for example. Is that possible withs sapply or the data.table solutions?

Comment: I think it works if you replace `transform(count = sapply(Date, \(x) sum(x >= begin & x <= end)))` by something like `transform(count = c(sapply(Depart, \(d){ b <- begin[id_depart == d]; e <- end[id_depart == d]; sapply(Date[Depart == d], \(x) sum(x >= b & x <= e)) })))`  where `Depart` is the unique departments added to the `data.frame` created at the start and `id_depart` is the department of each individual.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `fuzzjoin` -

```
library(dplyr)

method_fuzzy = function(df) {
  date_df = tibble(Date = seq(from=as.Date('2015-01-01'), 
                              to=Sys.Date(), by = "month"))

  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(date_df, df, 
                              by = c('Date' = 'begin', 'Date' = 'end'), 
                              match_fun = c(`>=`, `<=`)) %>%
    count(Date)
}

method_fuzzy(smallEmp)
```

Comment: It works, but it is significantly slower than the original solution. For about 50,000 employees the original solution took 7.2 sec, the fuzzy join took 1.35 min

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table` to perform the same operation very efficiently, using a ["non-equi join"](https://selbydavid.com/2021/02/13/joins/):

```r
small_emp <- data.table(
  begin = as.Date(
    c(
      "2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-27","2015-07-06","2015-06-29",
      "2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-13","2015-06-29",
      "2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-13","2015-07-01","2015-07-06",
      "2015-07-06","2015-07-06","2015-07-09","2015-07-13"
    ),
    format = "%Y-%m-%d"
  ),
  end = as.Date(
    c(
      "2018-08-03","2016-01-11","2999-12-31","2017-03-13","2999-12-31",
      "2015-10-20","2999-12-31","2018-09-24","2999-12-31","2015-09-25",
      "2019-11-01","2999-12-31","2018-03-26","2018-08-08","2015-10-13",
      "2999-12-31","2999-12-31","2021-02-11","2999-12-31"
    ),
    format = "%Y-%m-%d"
  )
)

all_dates <- data.table(
  date = seq(from = as.Date('2015-01-01'), to = Sys.Date(), by = "month")
)

result2 <- all_dates[
    small_emp, .N, on = .(date >= begin, date <= end), keyby = .(date)
]
```

Note that the `on` specification for a non-equi join is a bit tricky. It is *not* an arbitrary R expression! It is a list of "operations" of the form `lhs_column %binop% rhs_column`. Specifically `date >= begin` is valid because `date` is a column in the left-hand table `all_dates`, and `begin` is a column in the right-hand table `small_emp`.

Moreover, the names of the columns specified in `on` will be discarded, and in this case replaced with `date.1`. I actually don't quite understand the rule here, and it's not well-documented from what I saw. Maybe someone can explain how this works in the comments!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a data.table approach using `foverlaps()`. Note that that this solution will perform much faster if you reduce your 2999-years to another (closer) unbelievable number like 2099.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(start  = begin, end = end)
answer <- data.table(date = seq(min(DT$start), max(DT$end), by = "1 days"))
answer[, dummy := date]
#set keys
setkey(DT, start, end)
setkey(answer, date, dummy)
#overlap join ans summarise
final <- foverlaps(DT, answer)[, .N, by = date]
# 1: 2015-06-29 2
# 2: 2015-06-30 2
# 3: 2015-07-01 3
# 4: 2015-07-02 3
# 5: 2015-07-03 3
# ---             
# 359581: 2999-12-27 8
# 359582: 2999-12-28 8
# 359583: 2999-12-29 8
# 359584: 2999-12-30 8
# 359585: 2999-12-31 8

#create nicer looking intervals
final[, .(from = min(date), to = max(date), N = min(N)), by = (id = rleid(N))]
#    id       from         to  N
# 1:  1 2015-06-29 2015-06-30  2
# 2:  2 2015-07-01 2015-07-05  3
# 3:  3 2015-07-06 2015-07-08 14
# 4:  4 2015-07-09 2015-07-12 15
# 5:  5 2015-07-13 2015-07-26 18
# 6:  6 2015-07-27 2015-09-25 19
# 7:  7 2015-09-26 2015-10-13 18
# 8:  8 2015-10-14 2015-10-20 17
# 9:  9 2015-10-21 2016-01-11 16
#10: 10 2016-01-12 2017-03-13 15
#11: 11 2017-03-14 2018-03-26 14
#12: 12 2018-03-27 2018-08-03 13
#13: 13 2018-08-04 2018-08-08 12
#14: 14 2018-08-09 2018-09-24 11
#15: 15 2018-09-25 2019-11-01 10
#16: 16 2019-11-02 2021-02-11  9
#17: 17 2021-02-12 2999-12-31  8
```

Comment: Great ideas. Instead of using the 2999 date I used sys.Date(), because we only care what the situation is until today, we don't know what will happened tomorrow.